# looking for a function to perform a more sofisticated job than underscore.js's extend function

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I wonder if there is some helper JavaScript library that has a function similar to underscore.js's `_.extend`.
What I am looking for is a function that given an associative array like the following:

```
{ foo: 1, bar: 2 }
```

and another "extending" associative array like the following:

```
{ foo : 3 }
```

can easily build the following "augmented" structure:

```
{ foo: [1, 3], bar: 2 }
```

otherwise I have to do it manually, but this task seems general enough to be a function in some helper library.

**clarification with an example on what should happen with different objects:**

base object: `{ foo: 1, bar: 2 }`

extending object: `{ quuz: 3, bar: 4 }`

result: `{ foo: 1, bar: [2, 4], quuz: 3 }`

Actually, now it is clear to me that the operation is commutative (base and extending can be switched with the result being always the same)

**additional example:**

base object: `{ foo: 1, bar: [2,5] }`

extending object: `{ foo: {a: 'A', b: 'B'} , bar: 4 }`

result: `{ foo: [1, {a: 'A', b: 'B'}], bar: [2, 4, 5], quuz: 3 }`

Comment: I don't know of any such function. What have you attempted so far? Any problem?

Comment: Some libraries might have a `transpose` function that could do a similar thing. However, it should be trivial to define it yourself - have you tried it?

Comment: It's also not very clear as to what you expect to happen with different objects. Some clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: Please put your solution in an answer only :-)

Comment: @Bergi but this is what I did!

Comment: Sorry, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/22113750/5) didn't really look like… Maybe you meant something different than "*finally: my solution*" :-)

Comment: @Bergi oh, you edited it. I didn't notice. Yep, you are right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**my solution**

I wrote the following functions `blend` and `blend_many` that, combined,
are able to recursively "blend" the two objects.

```
/**
 * applies blend to all the objects contained in the input list.
 * The output is an object that contains a blend of all the input objects.
 */

function blend_many(list) {
    var ret = _.reduce(list, blend, {});
    for (var key in ret) {
        var value = ret[key];

        if (_.isArray(value)) {
            var all_are_objects = _.reduce(value, function (a, b) {
                return a && _.isObject(b);
            }, true);
            if (all_are_objects) {
                // recurse!
                value = blend_many(value);
            }
        }
        ret[key] = value;
    }
    return ret;
}

function blend(base, extending) {
    for (key in extending) {
        var value = extending[key];

        if (_.isArray(value)) {
            // recurse
            value = blend_many(value);
        }

        if (base[key] === undefined) {
            base[key] = value;
        } else if (_.isArray(base[key])) {
            base[key].push(value)
        } else {
            var prev = base[key];
            base[key] = [prev, value];
        }
    }
    return base;
}
```

for example, calling:

```
list_of_objs = [
  {
    a: {
      foo: 1
    }
  },
  {
    a: {
      foo: 2
    }
  }
];
blend_many(list_of_objs);
```

will return the following object:

```
{
  a: {
    foo: [ 1, 2 ]
  }
}
```

(very useful for building mongodb queries!)

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement is not very clear, what do you want to happen with different objects? But, this is a shallow extend that does what you seem to be asking, or use it as a base for your experiments and tweek it to your design.

Javascript

```
function curstomExtend(target) {
    var typeTarget = typeof target;

    if (target === null || typeTarget !== 'object' && typeTarget !== 'function') {
        throw new TypeError('target');
    }

    Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1).forEach(function (source) {
        var typeSource = typeof source;

        if (source === null || typeSource !== 'object' && typeSource !== 'function') {
            throw new TypeError('source');
        }

        Object.keys(source).forEach(function (key) {
            var temp;

            if (target.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                if (Array.isArray(target[key])) {
                    target[key].push(source[key]);
                } else {
                    target[key] = [target[key]];
                    target[key].push(source[key]);
                }
            } else {
                target[key] = source[key];
            }
        });
    });

    return target;
};

var a = {
    foo: 1,
    bar: 2,
    fy: {
        a: 1,
        b: 2
    }
},
b = {
    foo: 3,
    fy: {
        s: 3,
        t: 4
    }
},
c = {
    foo: [4, 5]
},
d = {
    foo: {
        x: 4,
        y: 5
    },
    fy: {
        s: 5,
        t: 6
    }
};

curstomExtend(a, b, c, d);

console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
```

Output

```
{"foo":[1,3,[4,5],{"x":4,"y":5}],"bar":2,"fy":[{"a":1,"b":2},{"s":3,"t":4},{"s":5,"t":6}]}
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/2S2Qk/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, my idea was to have a result that has, for example, the `foo` element as having the following value: `[1,3,4,5,{"x":4,"y":5}]` (when it is a list, then it will be merged)

Comment: That's a very simple modification to the above, just test the condition: if the target (already done) is array then if source is an array then use `concat` else `push`